# Why isn't Angular's $scope accessible inside my call to Google App Engine data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-app-engine

I'm trying to create a controller that gets data from Google app engine and allows me to display it on a page. The problem seems to be that the data (resp) can be accessed locally, but I can't seem to access it outside of the function. I am able to do so if I simply use javascript (...document.getElementById('getListingsResult').innerHTML = result;...), but if I invoke $scope for Angular, I can't access it any longer. Does anyone have any idea of how I can fix it while retaining the same structure to load and call gapi? Heres' my code:

(edit: added $scope.loadData, but problem persists)

```
    phonecatControllers.controller('datastoreTestCtrl', ['$scope',  
        function($scope) {
            $scope.data;
           $scope.loadData = function() { 
           var ROOT = 'https://my_team.appspot.com/_ah/api';
           gapi.client.load('listingserviceapi', 'v1',  function(){
               console.log("reached step 1");
           var request = gapi.client.listingserviceapi.getListings();
           request.execute(function (resp){

                  if (!resp.code) {
                      // console.debug(resp);
                       console.log('loaded! :)');//returns loaded
                       resp.items = resp.items || [];   
                       $scope.data = resp.items;
           console.log($scope.data); //returns an array of data
                   }   
           };
        } , ROOT  );};
   $scope.loadData;
           console.log($scope.data); //returns [object, object] which is incorrect
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work using promise. Also, there is a missing parenthesis for request.execute function in your code.

Check the below code (untested):

```
phonecatControllers.controller('datastoreTestCtrl', ['$scope', '$q',

function ($scope, $q) {
    $scope.data = null;

    $scope.loadData = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer(),
            ROOT = 'https://my_team.appspot.com/_ah/api';

        gapi.client.load('listingserviceapi', 'v1', function () {
            console.log("reached step 1");
            var request = gapi.client.listingserviceapi.getListings();
            request.execute(function (resp) {
                if (!resp.code) {
                    // console.debug(resp);
                    console.log('loaded! :)'); //returns loaded
                    resp.items = resp.items || [];
                    //$scope.data = resp.items;
                    //console.log($scope.data); //returns an array of data
                    deferred.resolve(resp.items);
                }
            }); //---missing parenthesis here
        }, ROOT);

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    $scope.loadData().then(function (data) {
        $scope.data = data;
        console.log($scope.data); //returns [object, object] which is incorrect
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your code and get an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'load' of undefined." Something seems to be throwing it off.

Comment: gapi.client.load? did you check if gapi.client is exist?

Comment: it exists and works fine when I use regular javascript. It must be raising an exception, but I don't think it is really a load problem, because I have been able to print out things to the console from within that function before. I think it's getting close though.

Comment: umm, strange! Do you see a line number at the error. You can put a debugger to find whatever that undefined is

Comment: This is strange. When I delete the last console.log($scope.data), it works, but not consistently. Right now it seems to be working and hopefully it continues to do so, but I'll try to check and see if it's maybe a datastore issue. Anyways, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are doing asynchronous call. When you trying to access $scope.data from outside of your callback your request is not finished yet it is still in process. You have to make sure that your request is done.

Comment: Thanks. How can I do that? I just tried to create a variable temp that stores the data and then did $scope.data = temp; after "...ROOT);", but it still doesn't work. Can you elaborate on where I assign the scope?

Comment: I also tried to do var promise = gapi.client.load....,ROOT);
promise.then(function(data) {
        $scope.data = data;
    });   but still no luck :(